# Error: Cannot find module './models/user'

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, passport.js

I'm doing the following tutorial:

https://www.raymondcamden.com/2017/02/08/using-social-login-with-passport-and-node/

but the code for the file: `./models/user` referenced on the line:

```
var user = require('./models/user');
```

is not provided.

Then, I'm getting the error:

```
Error: Cannot find module './models/user'
```

The variable: `user` is used on the following lines:

```
var me = new user({
    email:profile.emails[0].value,
    name:profile.displayName
});

/* save if new */
user.findOne({email:me.email}, function(err, u) {
    if(!u) {
        me.save(function(err, me) {
            if(err) return done(err);
            done(null,me);
        });
    } else {
        console.log(u);
        done(null, u);
    }
});
```

But I have no idea about what should be the content of the file: `./models/user`.

Could you provide me some test content that makes this tutorial work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code on models/user file.

Just check it.

```
var mongoose=require("mongoose");
var passportlocalmongoose=require("passport-local-mongoose");
var UserSchema=mongoose.Schema({
    email: String,
    Password: String
});

UserSchema.plugin(passportlocalmongoose);
module.exports=mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```